# In WordPress, use the production media library on local server

Tags: wordpress

I am developing an E-Commerce website that handles thousands of images (images for product variations, old and new product images,...) and they are handled by the WordPress Media Library.

Is there any way to *sync* all those images directly from the production server to my local copy, instead of importing all of them? I mean, the images are located on the production server, I just want to call them.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an .htacess rewrite rule (or your specific environment equivalent to .htaccess rewrite) to redirect local image requests to the production server.

Something like this

```
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ http://productionserver.com/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Changing folder name and server url accordingly.